# How can I obtain a matrix from Hough Transform?

Tags: c#-4.0, image-processing, matrix, hough-transform

Please, refer to [this journal article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50282799_Multidirectional_Scratch_Detection_and_Restoration_in_Digitized_Old_Images).

In the paragraph **4.2** (***Line Direction Detection***),

> We observed that since each binary image is the output of a directional ﬁltering process, the Hough transform will give relevant information only in a neighborhood of that direction (shifted by 90◦ with respect of the input image). Therefore, for each direction, only this information is useful, and we saved
>   it as columns in a data matrix.

**What are they actually talking about?**

For instance, take a look at [this C# source code](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.Imaging/AForge.Imaging/HoughLineTransformation.cs#L261) at line 261,

```
public class HoughLineTransformation
{
... ... ...

private short[,] houghMap;

... ... ...
}
```

**Are they talking about this 2D array `houghMap`?**

If **NO**, how can I obtain that?

Answer (score 0):

They seem to have multiple input images which all orinate from a filter operation. Due to the different filtering each image contains only lines in a specific angle range so only a fraction of each hough accumulator array will contain useful information.

For further processing they do not use one hough accumulator array for each image, but combine the hough output for all images into a "data matrix".

So they simply reduce the amount of data by only taking those hough results that bear useful information and they combine it to a custom data structure.

Comment: How are they only choosing useful lines and getting rid of useless ones? What algorithm/logic are they using to do that?

Comment: @anonymous I did not say useful lines, I said useful information. a hough accumulator array will contain data for every possible parameter combination. if you know that due to your filtering only certain angles are in your input image you can discard all other parameter combinations. if you know you have only lines between 10 and 20 degrees you don't have to store or further process results for < 10 and > 20 degrees.